# Axios Post is not completing every time

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

Iam new to React and I got some problems.

This is my current API call.

```
Axios.post(Addr_currentRound_addOne, { gameId: gameId }).then(history.push("/leiter_tunierplan/"+gameId));
```

And this is the corresponding API Code snippet.

```
app.post("/currentRoundAddOne", (req, res) => {

  
  const gameId = req.body.gameId;
    
  db.query(
    "UPDATE tunierplan SET currentRound=currentRound+1 WHERE id=?;",
    [gameId],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.send("Daten Übertragen");
      }
    }
  );
});
```

The problem here:
currentRound, should allways when the call is executed increased by +1.
And then Redirect to the given "/leiter_tunierplan/"
BUT
From time to time, it does not work. Its not increasing it by any Value (+1)
My first thought is: Because its async it my be canceled from the history.push, befor it got completed. Am i right? And how can i fix it.
Thanks allready.

Comment: But nowhere in your code `gameId` gets incremented?

Comment: _"Because its async it my be canceled from the history.push, befor it got completed. Am i right?"_ - no, because with `then` you are using a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and that takes async out of the equation to begin with - the history push will only occur, when the response to your request has arrived.

Comment: gameId is not relevant. @Jer

Comment: You are complaining about it not being _incremented_. Nothing in your code shows it being incremented.

Comment: So: how can i fix it then?
Because it should only redirect when Axios.post is finished.

Comment: gameId is a Fix Value. currentRound should be incremented. As the MYSQL querry says

Answer (score 1):

Is game `gameId` the already incremented id for the next page? I don't see it being incremented anywhere in your code.

If so, try putting history.push in a callback, like this:

```
...then(() => history.push("/leiter_tunierplan/"+gameId));
```

This is because `then` takes a callback function as a parameter

Comment: Maybe its a bit confusing here. gameId is an ID that is not changing the whole game.
Its just there to determine which game you are currently in.
The game has multiple Rounds. And currentRound should increase in the DB in dependecy from the GameId.

Comment: I just tried your Solution, and it aint working.
I would appreciate any other Solution, that at first executes the API call and then executes the history push. Thanks in regard

Answer (score 0):

The Solution to all is to add `preventDefault();`
My Problem was, that the side got reloaded..

Answer (score 0):

I think you try `async`-`await` as the request to the database is promise-based.
My suggestion:

```
app.post("/currentRoundAddOne", async (req, res) => {
    const gameId = req.body.gameId
    const data = await db.query("UPDATE tunierplan SET currentRound=currentRound+1 WHERE id=?;", [gameId],
    (err, result) => {
          if (err) console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(data) // check updated data, it should return id
})
```

I hope it works!